# Adding Data in Data base using EXCEL FILE with SYMFONY3

Tags: symfony

is there anyone anyone who used EXCEL FILE to add data in data base with symfony3 ! thanks !

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it would be better to share what you have tried and then people would be able to start helping you.

Comment: Yes.  I frequently import excel data into a database.  And I even export as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue few months ago.
I ended up writing [this class](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1660659) with the function [`getArrayFromCsv()`](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1660659#L18).
Using it, all you have to do is to save your excel file as a .csv, then pass the file to the function, and you'll get an array of your data so that you can process them as you wish.

More explained, you can just use `str_getcsv` php function with some csv content as parameter, or `fgetcsv` if you pass a resource instance of the csv file.

And then, process your data.

---

Here is an example of a fixture load() function using that class as dependency; as a way of using it with symfony:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->onLoadStart($manager);//A custom processing to initialize the fixture object instance

    $setLineKeys = function ($keysRow) {//A callback to redefine the keys of the obtained array of data

        return $this->setLineKeys($keysRow);
    };

    $clients = CollectionUtil::getArrayFromCsv($this->getFileName(), NULL, NULL, NULL, $setLineKeys);//We read the file and put the data in an array structure

    $noAddress = [];

    foreach ($clients as $clientData) {// We process the array in order to build entities

        foreach ($clientData as $key => &$value) {

            $value = trim($value);
        }

        $client = (new Client())

            ->setName($clientData['name'])

            ->setAbbreviation(substr($clientData['abbreviation'], 0, 6))

            ->setBillable($this->isBillableGuess($clientData))

            ->setSector($this->getSector($clientData, $manager))

            ->setAddress($this->getAddress($clientData))

            ->setAccountingData($this->getAccountingData($clientData))

            ->setSite($this->defaultSite)

            ->setOrganization($this->defaultSite->getOrganization())
        ;

        !$clientData['telephone'] ?:
            $client->addPhone((new Phone($clientData['telephone']))->setPrimary(true))
        ;

        !$clientData['email'] ?:
            $client->addEmail((new Email($clientData['email']))->setPrimary(true))
        ;

        !$clientData['fax'] ?:
            $client->addFax((new Fax($clientData['fax']))->setPrimary(true))
        ;

        if (NULL == $client->getAddress()) {

            $noAddress[$clientData['abbreviation']] = $clientData['name'];
        } else {

            $this->buildCode($client);

            $manager->persist($client);
        }
    }

    $manager->flush();// We persist all the entities we just built.
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate/explain, what you did in the class? (So this answer will still be useful if the linked file is offline)

Comment: Hi @kero, I think that the phpdoc at the head of the getArrayFromCsv function clear enough to explain what is done by the function... Anyway, if something specific seems unclear to you, just ask and I'll be glad to answer. :)

Comment: It is not about me personally, in fact I did this task myself in a very similar way. Moreover, [link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Okay, now I get you

Comment: Hey Bernardin EBASSA did you use EXCEL in symfony ! thanks for your answer btw

Comment: Hello, as a way of using it in symfony, you can just add this submentioned class in a bundle, and then inject it in fixtures where you will read from your data files, process them as arrays, build the desired entities and finally persist them.